# What are the benefits of whisking when making muffins?

Tags: muffins

What are the benefits of whisking when making muffins?

Comment: We're going to need more context than that. Primarily, what are you whisking? Oh, I see the tag now. You're whisking muffins? Hmmm. That almost seems like your instructor might be asking a trick question.

Comment: I've edited muffins into your question, but it's still a little unclear what you're asking - more context would definitely help.

Comment: Although people are going to pile on with the 'whisking is bad' for muffins ... they didn't say they were whisking the liquids into the dry.  I occasionally whisk the dry ingredients to get good aeration and make sure the leavening is well mixed before I stir in the liquid.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is been answered [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21733/what-to-add-to-the-batter-of-the-cake-to-avoid-hardening-when-the-gluten-formati)

"Over mixing batter forms gluten, which in turn hardens the cake", @Theindependentaquarius.

"There's a difference between "don't overmix" and "don't mix" - you're supposed to mix enough to incorporate, just don't try homogenize it", @Aaronut.

Comment: Can you explain what whisking has to do with over/undermixing? (Given that muffin batter tends to be too thick to effectively whisk, it's kind of hard to say...)

Answer (score -3):

Whisking muffin batter.

> ... affects the entire leavening or raising process because no baking powder is used....
>
> This allows a greater number of cells to form and the cells contain a larger amount of air.
>
> Loss of aeration results in a smaller product with a coarse texture.
>
> Aeration is only successful if the air remains in the batter until it is baked. For large mixes, stabilisers and emulsifiers (or fats) are added during the whisking stage.
>
> (Source: [Cakes > Whisking Method](https://www.bakeinfo.co.nz/Facts/Cake-making/Whisking-method))

Whisking batter makes it smooth, silky, fluffy and free of lumps

Comment: I'm sorry, but I seriously doubt you can possibly whisk enough air by hand into muffin batter to leaven them.

Comment: @Jefromi so by your "opinion" I'm wrong? Nobody said it was by hand.  Whisking is also known as whipping,  which is either by hand or mixer. Don't down vote my answer because of your opinion. I answered the question.

Comment: In isolation, "whisking" definitely implies using a whisk to mix by hand. If a mixer is *required*, a recipe will generally state it.  (And even with a mixer, you really can't replace leavening. You could beat egg whites and fold them in to add a little fluff, but even then it won't do the same thing as baking powder.) In any case, I downvoted because I don't think this is a useful answer: this is not a good way to leaven muffins, and though the OP hasn't provided much context, it's most likely the question is simply about using it as a mixing method.

Comment: Also, though I'm happy to discuss with you, please do not respond like this to any other users who are kind enough to explain their voting. Everyone is welcome to vote how they like, and it's polite and helpful to explain in a comment. If they do and you disagree, by all means, explain why. But they were trying to help, so please don't be rude about it.

Comment: @Jefromi the questioner stated "benefits of whisking", in which I satisfied the answer. Just for FYI,  Kitchen Aid mixer comes with a whisk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17013/discussion-between-jefromi-and-hash-brown).

Comment: Answer now edited

Comment: The cake whisking method described in the source you cited is specifically intended for the egg portion of a batter. Not sure that can be extended to whisking any batter generally.